# How can I query WMI GroupUser objects and select PartComponent attribute

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wql, cmdb

I want to select Account attribute in this query

example : `SELECT Description, Disabled, Domain, FullName, Lockout, Name, SID FROM Win32_UserAccount  WHERE Domain = '<domainName>'`

I'm trying to get

```
SELECT PartComponent FROM Win32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent=`"Win32_Group.Domain='xxx',Name='xxx'`""
```

I am trying to fetch  attribute in partcomponent attribute but I can't get any result from the partcomponent